# Login not working in Android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to make login code but its not working. Always show login not correct or crash application.

1st file login_form.java:

```
package com.example.sourabhkumargupta.blood_donor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class login_form extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText email,password;
    Button login_button;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_form);

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    final DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           String pass = password.getText().toString();
            String login_checks = databaseHelper.login_check(email.getText().toString());


           if(password.getText().toString().equals(login_checks)){
               Toast.makeText(login_form.this,"DOne",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else
           {
               Toast.makeText(login_form.this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

2nd page is DatabaseHelper.java. This is for Database. I am returning string password from this file:

```
package com.example.sourabhkumargupta.blood_donor;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.annotation.Target;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        private static final String DATABASE_NAME  = "donor.db";
        private  static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_detail";
        private static final int version = 2;
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
  //          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }

    @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (USER_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
                    "USER_NAME TEXT, USER_EMAIL TEXT, USER_BLOOD TEXT, USER_PASSWORD TEXT )");
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion , int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);


    }

    public int cheking_unique(String email){
             SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWritableDatabase();


         //String query = new String("")
        Cursor check_unique = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE USER_EMAIL= ?",
                new String[]{email} );

        int count = check_unique.getCount();

           return count;

    }
    public boolean insert(String name, String email, String password, String blood){
        SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("USER_NAME",name);
        contentValues.put("USER_EMAIL",email);
        contentValues.put("USER_BLOOD",blood);
        contentValues.put("USER_PASSWORD",password);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)

          return false;
        else
          return true;
    }
  public String  login_check(String email){
      SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWritableDatabase();


            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE USER_EMAIL=?",new String[]{email});
            c.moveToFirst();
          String password= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USER_PASSWORD"));
           return password;

            }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Replace 'new String[]{email}' with 'email' and please, please take a look at @pretezurich 's comment

Comment: getting this error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]

Comment: Please add your logcat

Comment: From a wild guess, app crash because of NullPointerException. If nothing can be found from the database, Cursor c will be null. Therefore a null check [if (c != null)] is need for using Cursor c. Hope that helps!